# In which varieties of English is it common to front predicates as in "Bought a nice house, he did."?

Tags: syntax, english, word-order, varieties

In which varieties of English is it common to front predicates as in the following sentence?

> Bought a nice house, he did.

In which pragmatic contexts is this done in these varieties?

Comment: Yoda-speak, perhaps?

Comment: I think it's particularly common in some regional varieties in England and maybe beyond in the UK. We say things like that in Australia too but nowhere near as often as I hear from some British people I meet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the varieties I know. I don't think it's regional, or varietal; it's just conversational, a sort of syntactic equivalent of Fast Speech Rules.

I suspect it's just an afterthought tag for Conversationally Deleted sentences like the ones Thrasher treats in his dissertation (Thrasher, Randolph H. Jr. 1974. *Shouldn't Ignore These Strings: A Study of Conversational Deletion,* Ph.D. Dissertation, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor). I posted about it on Linguist List [here](http://linguistlist.org/issues/2/2-737.html#2), [here](http://linguistlist.org/issues/4/4-121.html#3), and [here](http://linguistlist.org/issues/4/4-227.html#1).

That is, *"Bought a nice house"* is derivable, in context, from *"He bought a nice house"* by Conversational Deletion, and — in some cases, **and** if the speaker wishes — may be clarified at the end with a tag, whence the *Do*-Support.

Some other examples, derived from examples in Thrasher:

- *Gotta go now. ~ Gotta go now, I do.*
- *See you next Tuesday. ~ See you next Tuesday, I will.*
- *Too bad about old Charlie. ~  Too bad about old Charlie, it was.*
- *Been in Ann Arbor long? ~ Been in Ann Arbor long, have you?*
- *Ever get a chance to use your Dogrib? ~ Ever get a chance to use your Dogrib, do you?*

This doesn't work in every case of Conversational Deletion, since not every deleted initial sequence can form an appropriate tag:

- *No need to get upset about it. ~* **No need to get upset about it, there is.*
- *Last person I expected to meet was John.  ~* **Last person I expected to meet was John, the.*

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly common in Welsh English, particularly in the South.  Usually done for emphasis such as "Fed up, I am". You can find more about it in The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language